# How to use five button with five image selection in imagePickerControllerDelegate method

Tags: ios, swift

I tried to upload 5 images to server and I have 5 button and five `ImageView`. if click the first button the first ImageView should be get image and same as like all button should select the represent `ImageView`. but the issue is if I click first button or any button and choosing image from gallery the fifth `ImageView` only getting image.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

    guard let image1 = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage]
        as? UIImage else {
            return
    }
    print(image1)
  //  firstImg.image = image1 as UIImage
    if addAttachBtn1.isSelected == true{
         firstImg.image = image1 as UIImage
    }else if addAttach2.isSelected == true{
        secondImg.image = image1 as UIImage
    }else if addAttach3.isSelected{
        thirdImg.image = image1 as UIImage
    }else if addAttach4.isSelected{
        fourthImg.image = image1 as UIImage
    }else{
        fifthImg.image = image1
    }

    dismiss(animated:true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: So I guess that `addAttachBtn1.isSelected` or any other one returns false. `isSelected` isn't working as you think it is.

Comment: You need to manually set `isSelected` to true for the button, when it is clicked. Alternatively (and better) you might make a property, that would store the index of the clicked button. Then you can check this property instead of `isSelected`.

Comment: @VikashKumar thank you for your edit, I've approved it. Note that you may also fix the method name in the title and remove the generic "_can anyone help me_" variations.

Comment: thank you , i fixed the issue by declaring the tag value for every button and its working fine now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 i declared five flags for five button.and i gave tag for each button.


var flag1 = 0
var flag2 = 0
var flag3 = 0
var flag4 = 0
var flag5 = 0
```

i gave five target action for five button

```
    addAttachBtn1.addTarget(self,action: #selector(selectFirstImage), for: .touchUpInside)
    addAttach2.addTarget(self,action: #selector(selectSecondImage), for: .touchUpInside)
    addAttach3.addTarget(self,action: #selector(selectThirdImage), for: .touchUpInside)
    addAttach4.addTarget(self,action: #selector(selectFourthImage), for: .touchUpInside)
    addAttach5.addTarget(self,action: #selector(selectFifthImage), for: .touchUpInside)


@objc func selectFirstImage(sender: UIButton){
    addAttachBtn1.tag = 1
    flag1 = 1
    alertControllerPOPupView()
    addAttachBtn1.titleLabel?.text = str_Url_name
}

@objc func selectSecondImage(sender: UIButton){
    addAttach2.tag = 2
    flag2 = 2
    alertControllerPOPupView()
    addAttach2.titleLabel?.text = str_Url_name
}
@objc func selectThirdImage(sender: UIButton){
    addAttach3.tag = 1
    flag3 = 1
    alertControllerPOPupView()
    addAttach2.titleLabel?.text = str_Url_name
}
@objc func selectFourthImage(sender: UIButton){
    addAttach4.tag = 1
    flag4 = 1
    alertControllerPOPupView()
}

@objc func selectFifthImage(sender: UIButton){
    flag5 = 1
    addAttach5.tag = 1
    alertControllerPOPupView()
}
```

afterThat i declared the alertController for imagePicking And videoPicking from Gallery

```
 func alertControllerPOPupView(){

    let aletcontroller:UIAlertController = {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Choose Pic From..", message: "please select the picture source", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        let camera = UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default, handler: { (cameraAction) in

            if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera){

                let cameraPicker =  UIImagePickerController.init()
                cameraPicker.delegate = self
                cameraPicker.sourceType = .camera
                cameraPicker.allowsEditing = false
                self.present(cameraPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        })

        let saveAlbum = UIAlertAction(title: "Picture", style: .default, handler: { (galleryAction) in

            if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.photoLibrary){
                let cameraPicker =  UIImagePickerController.init()
                cameraPicker.delegate = self
                cameraPicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
                cameraPicker.allowsEditing = false
                self.present(cameraPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        })

        let VideoAlbm = UIAlertAction(title: "Video", style: .default, handler: { (galleryAction) in

            if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.photoLibrary){
                let libraryPicker = UIImagePickerController.init()
                libraryPicker.delegate = self
                libraryPicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
                libraryPicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String,kUTTypeVideo as String]
                libraryPicker.allowsEditing = false
                    self.present(libraryPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }

        })

        let cancelButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(camera)
        alert.addAction(VideoAlbm)
        alert.addAction(saveAlbum)
        alert.addAction(cancelButton)
        return alert
    }()

    self.present(aletcontroller, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

imagePicking from the galley and giving the path here

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

if flag1 == 1{

    flag1=0
    guard let image1 = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage]
        as? UIImage else {
            return
    }
    firstImg.image = image1 as UIImage
}

if flag2 == 2{

    flag2=0
    guard let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage]
        as? UIImage else {
            return
    }
    secondImageView.image = image as UIImage
}
if flag3 == 1{
    flag3=0
    guard let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage]
        as? UIImage else {
            return
    }
    thirdImageView.image = image as UIImage
}

if flag4 == 1{
    flag4 = 0
    guard let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage]
        as? UIImage else {
            return
    }
    fourthImageView.image = image as UIImage
}
if flag5 == 1{
    flag5 = 0
    guard let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage]
        as? UIImage else {
            return
    }
    fifthImageView.image = image as UIImage
}
dismiss(animated:true, completion: nil)
```

}

Comment: finally i am adding this all images to array . i hope this will help you to do it eassily